# Bootstrap with React: accordion won't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to get a bootstrap accordion running, where my panels are React classes. Somehow this doesn't work:

```
<ReactBootstrap.Accordion>
   <WontWorkPanel pkey={1} />
   <WontWorkPanel pkey={2} />
</ReactBootstrap.Accordion>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3azxcquh/

The `WontWorkPanel` is React class that renders the single panel with the key `this.props.pkey` .

Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong, or how to do it better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Accordion clones its children with new props, and those props control the showing/hiding of the `Panel` component. To allow that to still work with a custom `Panel` wrapper, you need to transfer props from the wrapper to the `Panel` child:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/3azxcquh/6/

```
var WontWorkPanel = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return this.transferPropsTo( 
      <ReactBootstrap.Panel header={"WontWork " + this.props.key} key={this.props.key}>
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life
        accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute,
        non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt
        laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua pu
      </ReactBootstrap.Panel>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: New information: transferPropsTo is deprecated. see: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/a6e220b7097eb3c79ab7 for detail.