# React-bootstrap accordion not working properly

Tags: javascript, accordion, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn react. Giving it a go, I was experimenting with react-bootstrap and was trying to implement accordion using react-bootstrap accordion. First I tried using ButtonToolBar, it worked fine.

```
var ButtonToolbar = ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar;
var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
var buttonsInstance = (
    <ButtonToolbar>
      <Button>Submit</Button>
      <Button>Cancel</Button>
    </ButtonToolbar>
);

React.renderComponent(
    buttonsInstance,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

But, react-bootstrap's accordion code wasn't working. It was showing the contents but not like we've in case of accordion. Here's the code:

```
var Accordion = ReactBootstrap.Accordion;
var Panel = ReactBootstrap.Panel;

var accordionInstance = (
    <Accordion>
      <Panel header="Collapsible Group Item #1" key={1}>
        Content1
      </Panel>
      <Panel header="Collapsible Group Item #2" key={2}>
        Content2
      </Panel>
      <Panel header="Collapsible Group Item #3" key={3}>
        Content3
      </Panel>
    </Accordion>
);

React.renderComponent(
    accordionInstance,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I also tried using , it also behaved the same. I was taking help from [here](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#jumbotron).

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886660/bootstrap-with-react-accordion-wont-work). But, in my case I can't have it working in without customizing the ReactBootstrp.Panel.

Any Idea, how can I get it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I hope that you've already found the answer to your question, but the following code should work. I think you simply need to change `key={}` to `eventKey={}` Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactPropTypes = React.PropTypes;
var Accordion = require('react-bootstrap').Accordion;
var Panel = require('react-bootstrap').Panel;    

var LeftSideInfo = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    var open = 3;
    return (
      <Accordion>
        <Panel header="Recommended Assignments" eventKey='1'>
          Some Info here
        </Panel>
        <Panel header="Candidate Information" eventKey='2'>
          More Info here
        </Panel>
        <Panel header="Contact Information" eventKey={open}>
          Yet another Panel
        </Panel>
       </Accordion>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = LeftSideInfo;
```

As a side note, I'm trying to figure out how to stop it from closing one panel when another one is clicked open. I think I just need to play with the `eventKey`

Comment: @QuietOmen did you manage to open multiple react bootstrap accordions at the same time?

Comment: @HuwDavies I'm guessing you mean having multiple accordions on a single page and their states being handled separately? If so, I haven't messed with this code for a little over a year. So I don't remember if I had multiples at the same time. If you post a question and link to it here, I'd be happy to try and help you find a solution.

Comment: @QuietOmen multiple accordions open yes so I guess they'd have to be handled separately. I'll be attempting it later today and next week so if I run into real trouble I'll let you know ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use Panels separately  to keep multiple panels open. Accordion will collapse the inactive panels automatically.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please flesh out your answer by adding at least a code example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with beta 8 version.
Using npm i react-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.9 fixed the issue.

Comment: The question was asked five years ago, you reference versions from April and May of 2019, and the current version is far past 1.0.0-beta.9. Can you explain?