# Bootstrap accordion is not expanding when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4

The bootstrap accordion is not expanding when clicked. I have installed bootstrap and jquery using npm as local dependency and imported both in root component i.e., App.js but for some reason jquery isn't detected it seems. Please correct me If I am doing something wrong.

GenerateMethods component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { browserHistory, Link } from 'react-router';
import Button from 'mineral-ui/Button';
import Popover from 'mineral-ui/Popover';
import Add from 'mineral-ui-icons/IconAdd';
import Delete from 'mineral-ui-icons/IconDelete';
import _ from 'lodash';

export class GenerateMethods extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rows: []
        }
    }

    render(){
        let content = [];
        const iconDelete = <Delete />;    
            this.props.uniqueMethods.map((d, i) => {
                let id = `#${d.id}`;
                let elements = <div className="panel list-group">
                    <a href="#" className="list-group-item default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target={id} data-parent="#menu">
                        <b>{d.method}</b> <span className="label label-info">5</span><span className="pull-right" onClick={() => this.props.handleDelete(d.id, d.method)} title="Remove this entry"><Delete /></span>
                    </a>
                    <div id={id} className="sublinks collapse">
                        <div className="list-group-item">
                            TEST4
                        </div>
                        <div className="list-group-item">
                            TEST5
                        </div>
                        <div className="list-group-item">
                            TEST6
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


                content.push(elements)
            });
        return(
            <div id="menu">
                {content}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Versions:

> "bootstrap": "^3.3.6", "jquery": "^2.2.3",

App.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="App">
            <!-- this is where the root react component will get rendered -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-bootstrap accordion not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012800/react-bootstrap-accordion-not-working-properly)

Comment: On more about integrationg React with DOM manipulating libraries, such as jQuery, read [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html). As a workaround, you can use `window.$` instead of `$` in your code (not recommended). Also read [React + jQuery](http://tech.oyster.com/using-react-and-jquery-together/).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I am not using jquery $ sign anywhere in my component. The $ sign that you see in my code is actually template literals expression

Comment: Why do you think `bootstrap.js` requires `jquery.js`, Hemadri? Or, to be more exact, how do you think the bootstrap collapse works? It's a `$('.collapse').collapse()` call. It's just that Bootstrap makes it for you, you don't have to init them yourself (you simply use classes).

Comment: If you want to use Bootstrap, use react-bootstrap, which has the components "react"-ified. You shouldn't expect adding jQuery + jQuery dependent libraries to simply work.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiGheorghiu

Answer (score 1):

React works on virtual DOM where as jquery works directly on DOM.I would suggest you to use [react-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap) package which is meant for react without using jquery.

However,if you want to use bootstrap with jquery in react then you can also include bootstrap dependencies in the index.html as `cdn` or store the bootstrap dependencies as `local files` in public folder.And also uninstall bootstrap dependencies from npm.

Comment: Ok I removed bootstrap and jquery and installed react-bootstrap. So does this also supports the bootstrap classes which I am already using in my components or do I need bootstrap lib as well if react-bootstrap doesn't support bootstrap css class names?

Comment: react-bootstrap has its own built in react components and controlled by its props defined.You don't need to declare any classes.You don't need external bootstrap library when using with react-bootstrap.

Comment: Understood Karthik but, my question is I have bootstrap classes in many components. So will that work if I remove bootstrap and install react-bootstrap?

Comment: ok,It does not work.if you are already using bootstrap in many components then don't install react-bootstrap.just add jquery and popper.min.js in the index.html .So that there wont be any issues.